# iptables mac address filtering not work

Tags: 11.10, firewall, iptables

I block every port default by ufw

and add iptables rules like this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j ACCEPT
```

then I list iptables INPUT rules:

```
sudo iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target                    prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT                    udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
2    ACCEPT                    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
3    ACCEPT                    udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps
4    ACCEPT                    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps
5    ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ufw-before-input          all  --  anywhere             anywhere
7    ufw-after-input           all  --  anywhere             anywhere
8    ufw-after-logging-input   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
9    ufw-reject-input          all  --  anywhere             anywhere
10   ufw-track-input           all  --  anywhere             anywhere
11   ACCEPT                    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 MAC 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

but I can't visit my server:1723

Is there sth wrong?

I use Ubuntu 11.10

Edit01:

I add followed things:

```
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines

-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 1723 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j ACCEPT
```

and then I list the rules

```
sudo iptables -L  ufw-before-input  --line-numbers
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num  target           prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1723 MAC 00:11:22:33:44:55
2    ACCEPT           all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ACCEPT           all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    ufw-logging-deny all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
5    DROP             all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
6    ACCEPT           icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp destination-unreachable
7    ACCEPT           icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp source-quench
8    ACCEPT           icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded
9    ACCEPT           icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp parameter-problem
10   ACCEPT           icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
11   ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
12   ufw-not-local    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
13   ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
14   ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250     udp dpt:1900
15   ufw-user-input   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

and still not work... of course, after `sudo service ufw restart` I still connect the server on 1723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are both machines on the same ethernet subnet? mac addresses are only local to a subnet. If there's a router inbetween, the server will see the mac address of the last router the packet crosses.

Also, `iptables -v -L` is handy for debugging, as you can see which rules are being triggered.

Comment: I don't know the rule! Is there any way to filter mac address through internet?

Comment: @TonyLee. No. And MAC addresses can be trivially spoofed anyway, so restricting my MAC-address isn't going to provide much security.

Comment: Can I filter mac address after connected by vpn?

Comment: You can filter by mac address whenever you are on the same subnet. So if the VPN is a single subnet containing the client and server, then yes.

Comment: I have tested. I connect my server by pptp through internet. then my IP is 10.0.0.2, server's ip is 10.0.0.1. and the mac address filter rules not work. so thank you very much @tumbleweed

Comment: Sorry, should have added, also, only if the VPN is ethernet based. PPTP isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Rule 9 in your `INPUT` chain jumps to `ufw-reject-input`, which in turn rejects the packet.

If you want your additions to function with `ufw`, I suggest reading the documentation shown by `man ufw-framework`.

You can probably achieve what you want by creating a `/etc/ufw/before.rules` file with content like:

```
*filter
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 1723 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: thanks for your help @jamesh. I add things you adviced but still not work. see my question's edit01.